# on-off button on angular2 using Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular

I am using `angular2` with `typescript`.
How can I create an `on - off` button?.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more what you try to accomplish. Have you read the Angular tutorials? Can you please add some code that demonstrates what you have tried? See also the help menu about how to ask good questions.

Comment: Thanks , I  have to  use http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/examples.html. Bootstrap like on-off switch button on angular2 application with type script. However this is available in angularJs but in angular2 i have to use it.

Comment: Building such a button is mostly about CSS not about Angular. In Angular you have just a state (on/off) and an input and ouput property to set the state and notify about state changes.

Comment: your question has not any concern with `typescript` and `angular2` i think this is just the matter of `css and javascript` but still i have posted the answer hope you may like it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes for you here is a stylish Switch (on/off toggle) using Bootflat theme (i have used Bootflat theme for styling [refer here](http://bootflat.github.io/documentation.html)). Just Put this code as `HTML` and some styles you have to add.

> http://plnkr.co/edit/BoiiICbQLKBtePJlsfHZ?p=preview

here is Code for Switch:

```
<label class="toggle col-sm-8">
  <input type="checkbox"(click)="Existing()">
  <span class="handle" style="top:0 !important"></span>
</label>

<h2 class='bg-danger'>Your Switch value Is  : {{value}}</h2>
```

Comment: Most of css code does the thing ! but good example...

Comment: If you are looking for a npm module then angular2-ui-switch is better option https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-ui-switch

Comment: you can also use Primeng's switch for the same here https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/inputswitch